# error al obtener variable fuera de un ciclo for

Tags: nodejs, bucles

estoy tratando de llenar un arreglo mediante la función push dentro de un ciclo for, si imprimo el arreglo dentro del ciclo me muestra los datos esperados, pero si imprimo el arreglo fuera del ciclo el arreglo me aparece vacío. Este es mi código:

```
router.post('/prueba', function(req, res, next) {
    var datos = JSON.parse(req.body.datos);
    //console.log(datos);
    var items={};
    var resultados_seleccionados=[];

    for (var i in datos) {
        var tmp_cantidad=0;
        var resultadosDB="";
        var tmp_id="";
        for (var j in datos[i]) {
            if (datos[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                if(j=="idproducto"){
                    tmp_id=datos[i][j];
                    db.query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto ='"+tmp_id+"'",function(err,resultados){
                        resultadosDB=resultados;
                        console.log(resultadosDB[0].titulo);
                        var item = {id_producto:resultadosDB[0].id_producto,producto:resultadosDB[0].titulo,precio:resultadosDB[0].precio};
                        resultados_seleccionados.push(JSON.stringify(item)); 
                        console.log(resultados_seleccionados);
                    } );
                }else if(j=="cantidad"){
                    tmp_cantidad=datos[i][j];
                }
                //console.log("La clave es " + j+ " y el valor es " + datos[i][j]);
            }
        }
        console.log(resultados_seleccionados);
        console.log(resultadosDB);
    }
    console.log("resultado final");
    console.log(resultados_seleccionados);
});
```

Resultados en consola:

```
resultado fuera del for
[]

Resultado dentro del for
[
  '{"id_producto":2,"producto":"Manual 2","precio":"100","cantidad":"1"}',
  '{"id_producto":1,"producto":"Manual 1","precio":"150","cantidad":"1"}'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido, creo que el problema que tienes es debido a la respuesta de la promesa db.query()

Si lo pones fuera del **for** (este for está dentro de la respuesta del query) entonces ocurre primero la impresión, por eso te aparece vacío.

Te aconsejaría usar funciones asíncronas y la palabra **await** para hacer que espere.

Más o menos creo que el código podría quedar así:

```
if (j == "idproducto") {
    tmp_id = datos[i][j];

    let resultados = await db.query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto ='" + tmp_id + "'")

    resultadosDB = resultados;
    console.log(resultadosDB[0].titulo);
    var item = { id_producto: resultadosDB[0].id_producto, producto: resultadosDB[0].titulo, precio: resultadosDB[0].precio };
    resultados_seleccionados.push(JSON.stringify(item));
    console.log(resultados_seleccionados);
    


 } else if (j == "cantidad") {
        tmp_cantidad = datos[i][j];
}
```

Y al principio de la función debes declararla como "async"

```
router.post('/prueba', async function(req, res, next)
```

También te sugiero que no uses **var**, sino que en su lugar utilices **let** o **const**

Espero te sirva de algo.

Comment: Que tal, muchas gracias por su observación, he realizado los cambios que me sugirió, sin embargo, ahora me aparece el siguiente el error  "Cannot read property 'titulo' of undefined".

Comment: Puedes poner un console log de resultados?? debajo de  esta línea              
<<   let resultados = await db.query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto ='" + tmp_id + "'"); console.log(resultados) >>   Al parecer db.query() está devolviendo algún error